# How to move player from one mesh to another in the Navmesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, collider, navmesh

I am trying to get my player to teleport to a point in the mesh from a trigger that is activated in another mesh, more specifically in a ceiling. I tried this but it leaves me the player in a corner of the mesh where he is already.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))

    {
        _playerPrefab.transform.position = _initialposition.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is _playerPrefab defined? What is _initialPosition? There's a few confusing things here with your naming convention. You should never be moving a prefab (a prefab is a "template" and not a living Game Object). I also find it strange that you _initialPosition isn't already a Vector (hence "position").

Comment: `[SerializeField] private GameObject _playerPrefab;`

Comment: _ initial position is where I want to go, it is a transform. Sorry, the player is in the game

Comment: have a search you can link meshes together , you wouldnt need to move it specifically you would use a mesh link

Comment: How would that be? Can you show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve it by changing the position with tranform.position, disabling the navMesh Agent and setting the speed to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the warp function that the NavMesh agent provides :

```
_playerPrefab.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().Warp(_initialposition.transform.position)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the NavMesh API, your player needs to have a NavMeshAgent.

Then you can simply call `yourAgent.SetDestination(yourDestination)`